# Why use backtick with ${ in const in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am going through the angular tutorial and I see the below:

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

```
const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${hero.id}`;
```

Can someone explain why I need to use ` before ${ ? Since this is TypeScript and similar to JavaScript can I not use

```
this.heroesUrl + "/" + hero.id
```

Why do I need to use backtick and the `${` operation?

Comment: Those are called [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). You don't **have** to use them, you can definitely use the latter option, but isn't the first option much simpler?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That is called [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and it's a javascript feature, it is not typescript specific.

True, you can indeed replace this:

```
const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${hero.id}`;
```

With:

```
const url = this.heroesUrl + "/" + hero.id;
```

But it is sometimes more comfortable to use the template literals, especially when the string is made out of a lot of parts. i.e.:

```
const url1 = protocol + "://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + path + "." + extension;
const url2 = `${protocol}://${host}:${port}/${path}.${extension}`;
```

Comment: The second code block (from above) should have `+` before `hero.id`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Think it's just a part of the [ES6 template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and so TypeScript inherits/permits this (you're not forced to use them incidentally) because although TypeScript is a superset of ES5, it contains some ES6 features.

Comment: What ES6 features are not in TypeScript?